# Vectorise a nested loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a "super-nested" loop in Matlab to create an array `gamma`. The loop takes a lot of time to execute. I would like your help to vectorise the loop.

This is the code with explanations:

```
rng default
clear 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Parameters
L=2;
K=3;
n_draws=10^6;
mu_V=zeros(1, L+1);  
Sigma_V=eye(L+1);  
v_draws=mvnrnd(mu_V,Sigma_V,n_draws); %n_drawsx(L+1)
payoff=randn(n_draws, L+1); %n_drawsx(L+1)
v_upp=5;  
v_low=-5; 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Fill the array gamma
gamma=zeros(K+1,K+1,K+1,L+1,L+1); %allocate space for the array gamma
for k1=1:K+1 
    for k2=1:K+1
        for k3=1:K+1 
            for y=1:L+1  
                for y1=1:L+1
                    tic
                    integr=((nchoosek(K, (k1-1))*(((v_draws(:,1)-v_low).^(k1-1).*(v_upp-v_draws(:,1)).^(K-(k1-1)))./((v_upp-v_low).^K))).*...
                            (nchoosek(K, (k2-1))*(((v_draws(:,2)-v_low).^(k2-1).*(v_upp-v_draws(:,2)).^(K-(k2-1)))./((v_upp-v_low).^K))).*...
                            (nchoosek(K, (k3-1))*(((v_draws(:,3)-v_low).^(k3-1).*(v_upp-v_draws(:,3)).^(K-(k3-1)))./((v_upp-v_low).^K)))).*...
                             mvnpdf(v_draws,mu_V,Sigma_V).*...
                            (payoff(:,y)-payoff(:,y1)); %n_drawsx1  
                    gamma(k1,k2,k3,y,y1)=sum(integr)/n_draws; %average of elements of integr
                    toc
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

For example, with `K=3`, it takes around 20 sec to execute. In my actual exercise, `K=50` and it takes forever.

Comment: You loop in the first 3 dimensions until `K+1`, but your array has only `K` values along those dimensions. This means that the array will be repeatedly reallocated when writing at `K+1`. This will slow down execution. Also, it is most optimal to loop in the reverse order, the inner loop should be over the first dimension. Finally, you can speed up execution by not recomputing the same thing over and over again, for example compute `nchoosek(K, n)` once for each `n`, then reuse those values inside your loop.

Comment: The first three dimensions of the array are K+1, it was a typo and it is fixed now. I have implemented the other two suggestions but it is still quite slow.

Comment: Did you move all computations outside loops where they are recomputed unnecessarily? Move computations related to `y1` outside the 4 innermost loops, things related to `y` outside the 3 innermost loops, etc. Also, `mvnpdf(v_draws,mu_V,Sigma_V)` is constant (and probably quite expensive) and should be computed only once outside all loops. It's quite a bit of effort to avoid all duplicate computations, take your time to do so!

Comment: Once you've avoided all duplicate computations, you're more likely to see ways to vectorize the code, but vectorization is likely to not have a huge influence in this case (assuming you're on a newer MATLAB release, not Octave nor a 20-year-old MATLAB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save ~95% runtime from my testing by applying two main types of improvement

1. Compute things in the outermost loop possible, so that equivalent terms are not computed multiple times.
2. Vectorise the inner `y1` loop to remove it

All of the deltas between `v_upp`, `v_low`, and `v_draws` are constant because these vectors do not change in the loops, so can all be computed outside of the loops. So can the `mvnpdf`.

The code then looks something like this:

```
gamma=zeros(K+1,K+1,K+1,L+1,L+1); %allocate space for the array gamma
v_delta = v_upp-v_low;
v_delta_upp1 = v_upp-v_draws(:,1);
v_delta_upp2 = v_upp-v_draws(:,2);
v_delta_upp3 = v_upp-v_draws(:,3);
v_delta_low1 = v_draws(:,1)-v_low;
v_delta_low2 = v_draws(:,2)-v_low;
v_delta_low3 = v_draws(:,3)-v_low;
MVN = mvnpdf(v_draws,mu_V,Sigma_V);
y1=1:L+1;
for k1=1:K+1 
    term1 = (nchoosek(K, (k1-1))*((v_delta_low1.^(k1-1).*v_delta_upp1.^(K-(k1-1)))./(v_delta.^K)));
    for k2=1:K+1
        term2 = (nchoosek(K, (k2-1))*((v_delta_low2.^(k2-1).*v_delta_upp2.^(K-(k2-1)))./(v_delta.^K)));
        for k3=1:K+1 
            term3 = (nchoosek(K, (k3-1))*((v_delta_low3.^(k3-1).*v_delta_upp3.^(K-(k3-1)))./(v_delta.^K)));
            integr = term1 .* term2 .* term3 .* MVN;
            for y=1:L+1  
                integrp = integr .* (payoff(:,y)-payoff(:,y1)); %n_drawsx1  
                gamma(k1,k2,k3,y,y1)=sum(integrp)/n_draws; %average of elements of integr                
            end
        end
    end
end
```

You could further improve this by noticing things like

- You're calculating `nchoosek` of `1:K+1` inside every loop, it might be quicker to calculate an array of the `nchoosek` values up front and just index into it when looping.
- You're dividing by `n_draws` and multiplying by the `mvnpdf` term every loop iteration, is it quicker to just do these after the loop?

You'll get diminishing returns looking at things like this though.

Comment: You can do `term1 .* MVN` outside the `k2` loop, and the `.* term2` part outside the `k3` loop. But as you say, diminishing returns...

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks Cris, I mention at the end about doing the `mvn` multiplication outside the loop. I did also do some testing with de-nested loops to generate the entire `termi` matrices in a vectorised way, then the nested loop becomes an indexing exercise; seemed like the larger memory allocation time didn't outweigh the loop speed up, either that or MATLAB's JIT compilation is being clever and already handling that efficiently.

Comment: Yeah, larger memory tends to slow things down significantly enough to reverse the vectorization benefits. The JIT is really good these days, we need to stop being afraid of loops in MATLAB.

Comment: Thanks. I would still like to see how the performance compares to a full vectorised version. Is it possible?

Comment: Sure, give it a go... as I say I found even minor additional vectorisation steps made no performance improvement for me and only added RAM usage